# Build a scrapy project usint setuptools

Tags: python, scrapy, setuptools

I have a Scrapy project that need to be build, below the project structure:

```
.
├── cli.py
├── docs
│   ├── README.md
│   └── README.md.html
├── __init__.py
├── my_scrapy_project
│   ├── exporters.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── randomproxy.py
│   │   └── random_user_agent.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── website_extractor_1.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── website_extractor_2.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapy.cfg
├── setup.py
└── VERSION
```

Scrapy spiders are executed by `cli.py`, when I try to build this package it's doesn't inlcude the `cli.py`, if I put this file `cli.py` in `scripts` key in `setup.py` it doesn't found Scrapy settings when I use `get_project_settings`

Any help please?